# $y'=4-x^2y^2$ and slope field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation :
$y'=4-x^2y^2$.

Write slope field of this equation, and answer T/F:

$(a)$ The solution which includes $(x,y)=(0,0)$ has a local minima.

$(b)$ The solution which includes $(x,y)=(0,0)$ has a local maxima.

$(c)$ The solution which includes $(x,y)=(0,0)$ has at least one inflection point.

I can't get some things :

First of all, I used the slope field generator of desmos and get :
[[image: the slope field of <span class=]$y'=4-x^2y^2$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkD7W.png)

How am I supposed to draw my solutions with this slope field ?

For $(a),(b),(c)$ the answer is yes but I can't get why.

If $(x,y)=(0,0) \implies y'=4-0=4$, then how there is local minima, maxima, and inflection point?

I'd be grateful for your help!

Comment: Minima/maxima is the plural form, this should not be used for a single point. These are minimum/maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function has a positive slope at $(0,0)$, it must certainly turn around at some point by looking at the slope field. First, notice that your solution is continuous. Recall that solutions of a slope field cannot intersect.

1. If you start at the origin, and move down and to the left, which is what you would do with a positive slope, you will eventually hit a point on your slope field where the slope is negative. Hence, your solution must transition from negative to positive somewhere in between that, i.e. your solution has a local minimum.
2. The same logic applies here. Move up and to the right and you will hit a point where the slope changes to negative, so you have a local max somewhere between that.
3. A solution that contains a local max and local min must have an inflection point somewhere.